# Use password to calculate checksum for API requests

Tags: web-application, hash, integrity

I was wondering if it would be an effective way of securing an API by requiring all requests to be checksummed, salted with the users password (or a hashed version)? With securing I mean making it "impossible" for a third party to make requests in the name of someone else or alter the content. The content of the request would be non-private.

Imagine an API that allows a user to save a text, then the request (containing the user id, text, other information) would be hashed together with the password of the user which acts as a common and non-hardcoded secret between a client and the server. The server then checks if the checksum is correct and knows that the request has not been changed and originates from that user.

Is this something that is commonly done and if it's a bad idea - why and what can be done instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a hash for authentication is very reasonable, but it is a bit tricky to get right. You should use a [hash based message authentication](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) as it circumvents some subtle flaws. You can find reputable libraries that support it for most languages/platforms.

One drawback of this strategy is that it requires that the server have a clear text copy of the password. This is rarely advisable for user passwords. But using it for generated secrets is very useful.

One way to avoid the password storage is to require a username/password (or other) authentication step that returns a secure token generated by the server. The client can then use that token for signing and the server could validate it. If the token is an HMAC of key information from the login such as username, session timeout, etc..., the server doesn't need to store the token to verify it. But, at this point, you've basically recreated OAuth and should probably just use it.

All of this assumes that you're using SSL. Without that, it will be very hard to prevent MiTM, replay, and similar attacks.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer! I figured that if you use a hashed password as salt on the client side, you could use the hashed password as a shared secret? Then you would not have to store the plain text password.

Comment: The problem with using a hashed password is that if someone steals your DB table and gets hashed passwords, they don't need to crack them. They can just authenticate with the hash. This is called a [pass the hash vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_the_hash).

Comment: I understand, however, at least the attacker would not be able to use the password for other accounts of the user. An improvement would then be  to pass a token using a secure channel which is used as secret or access the api through a secure channel, as oleksii's answer suggest.

Comment: Are you planning on implementing this without SSL? My thought was that you would be using SSL in addition to the signing.

Comment: My thought was that the message authentication would make it possible to implement the API without SSL, making it easier for "simple" clients to use it, too. (I am not implementing it now, the idea interests me, however)

Comment: @Samuel There are too many attack vectors that you can't protect against without using SSL (TLS). Without a way for the computer to verify the legitimacy of your server there simply is no way to secure your connection against man-in-the-middle attacks. Not to mention replay attacks in which previously recorded encrypted data is re-sent back to the server (could be used to bypass login, etc). If the idea interests you, then maybe indulge in reading how TLS in itself works to secure your data. But do not attempt to create such a system yourself, for any purpose other than educational.

Comment: I strongly agree. it is very hard (ie: all but impossible) to be secure without SSL in the general case. There may be very restricted use cases where SSL is optional, but what you are talking about really requires SSL.

Comment: @JonathanGray You are right, I don't want to give the wrong impression, HTTPS is the best solution. As you mention, simply replaying a message would already be a problem. However, in simple clients such as microcontrollers / sensors implementing SSL is not so trivial. This made a simple salted checksum based approach seem attractive, it is easy to calculate and requires little data transfer (/ battery power).

Comment: @Samuel - what is the scope of your question? You don't mention microcontrollers in it. If you have a question about authentication for microcontrollers, you should post a new question.

Comment: @NeilSmithline I just wanted to provide the context which made me think about this issue. My goal was to obtain more information (such as HMAC) about this type of authentication and to get acquainted without the specific context of microntrollers and other protocols which usually also solve more than one issue. Therefore, I'm very happy about the input I got from you guys but I don't want to make the issue more specific and complete unless I actually ever want to implement something like this (in which case I will ask a new question)!

Answer (score 1):

This smells like homebrew with all the inherent problems. HTTPS addressed many possible attacks, including the ones you described. It will be naive to assume you/me/{anybody else alone} can come up with better alternatives. Unless such approach is peer-reviewed by large security community and proven by time.

Standard HTTPS with strong authentication resolves all your worries.

Comment: I value your opinion and I am sensitive to the issue of roll-your-own security. HTTPS would solve the problem, in that case you'd have to send the password along with the request though, yet, to make sure that it actually originates from the user. However, I feel that if my solution is a common approach to solving my problem I can also find a solid implementation for it.

Comment: @Samuel there's nothing wrong with sending the password with the request as long as the communication happens over a secure connection. TLS verifies the server before it sends any encrypted data to it. However if it's a system that could make use of a session then you'll want to look into how to use sessions securely in whatever environment you're working with.

Comment: @Samuel strong authentication can guarantee (to the best of our public knowledge) that request came from the client. If for example you can use 2 way authentication, where client verifies the server and server verifies the client by a certificate - it is as good as you can make it. Something like that https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=client%20certificate%20authentication&es_th=1#

Comment: @JonathanGray I agree that using HTTPS would be a solution for this problem, it was more of a note.

Comment: @oleksii Yes, but apart from the client e.g. another webpage, the *user* also needs to authenticate himself such that no-one can make request for a user that did not give his permission (password).